# KeyError when trying to assign clean_data value in Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I receive a KeyError when I try to assign a `form.clean_data['value']`
I'm trying to script an interest calculator in Django web app, which takes the user input of initial capital years and rate and calculates the final capital, however it returns a key error. The db is sqlite3.

Any help in the solution and design is appreciated, being a beginner and all..

Here's the traceback

Traceback:

> File
>   "/Users/Andras/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py"
>   in inner
>     39.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/Users/Andras/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "/Users/Andras/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "/Users/Andras/myproject/myapp/views.py" in query
>     37.             initial = form.cleaned_data['initial']
>
> Exception Type: KeyError at /query/ Exception Value: 'initial'

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Context 
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView 
from myapp.models import Queries
from django.core import serializers
import os, re, math
from django.template import Context
from django.views.generic import View
from django import forms
from myapp.forms import QueriesForm
import decimal
from django.http import Http404

def get_final(initial, rate, years):
    initial = self.initial
    rate = self.rate
    years = self.years
    calcInterest = (initial*(1+((rate/100)/12))^(12*years))
    final = calcInterest
    return final    


def query(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = QueriesForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            initial = form.cleaned_data['initial']
            rate = form.cleaned_data['rate']
            years = form.cleaned_data['years']

            init1 = Queries.objects.get_initial()
            rate1 = Queries.objects.get_rate()
            years1 = Queries.objects.get_years()
            final1 = get_final(init1, rate1, years1)

            return render (request, 'result.html', {'cacl':final1})

        else:
        raise Http404
    else:

    form = QueriesForm()        

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})


def index(request):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    return render(request, "index.html", {})

def queries(request):
    template_name = 'queries.html'
    return render(request, "queries.html", {}) 

def result(request):
    template_name = 'result.html'
    return render(request, "result.html", {})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Queries


class QueriesForm(forms.Form):


    initial = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'max_lenght':10, 'requred':True})
    years = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'max_lenght':10, 'requred':True})
    rate = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'max_lenght':10, 'requred':True})

def clean_message(self):
    initial = self.cleaned_data.get("initial")
    years = self.cleaned_data.get("years")
    rate = self.cleaned_data.get("rate")


class Meta:

    model = Queries
    fields = ('initial', 'years', 'rate',)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Queries(models.Model):

    initial = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places = 2)
    years = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places = 2)
    rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places = 2)

def get_initial(self):
    return self.initial

def get_years(self):
    return self.years

def get_rate(self):
    return self.rate
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'myapp'
    urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'),
    url(r'^queries/', views.queries, name = 'queries'),
    url(r'^query/', views.query, name = 'query')

]
```

index.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>My Cool Savings Calculator</title>
<style>
 h1 {
  padding-bottom: 0em;
  margin-bottom: 0em;
}
table {
  padding-top: 0em;
  margin-top: 0em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Savings Calculator</h1>

<table>
<form name = "form" action = "{% url 'myapp:query' %}" method='POST'>{% csrf_token %}
<tr>
      <td><label>Initial Capital:</label>

  <td><input type='number' name='initial'></input></td>

 </tr>
 <br>
 <tr>
  <td><label>Number of Years:</label>

  <td><input type='number' name='years' value='5'></input></td>

 </tr>
<br>
<tr>
  <td><label>Interest rate (annual):</label>

  <td><input type='number' name='rate' value='3.5'></input></td>

</tr>
<br>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td><input type='submit'></input></td>
</tr>
</form>
 </table>
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}

<h3>Check previous queries <a href='/queries'>here</a></h3>
</body>
```

results.html

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}

{% block content %}


<h2>{{calc}}</h2>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned you might want to correct the spelling of max_length and required in your form fields.

Then also i think you need to actually output the form rather than the regular html inputs as you have done.

```
<form action="{% url 'myapp:query' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Then also in your views.py query function where its throwing the error you might want to use .get with a fallback value.

```
initial = form.cleaned_data.get('initial', 0)
rate = form.cleaned_data.get('rate', 3.5)
years = form.cleaned_data.get('years', 5)
```

Comment: thank you guys for the answers final figured out what was going wrong after correcting the typos and using the form :)

Answer (score 0):

You have typos in your attrs parameters, which may be the cause of this issue.

Try changing these three lines:

```
initial = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'max_lenght':10, 'requred':True})
years = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'max_lenght':10, 'requred':True})
rate = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'max_lenght':10, 'requred':True})
```

To this:

```
initial = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'max_length':10, 'required':True})
years = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'max_length':10, 'required':True})
rate = forms.NumberInput(attrs={'max_length':10, 'required':True})
```